# Visual Studio 2010/2012 - Exceptions occur for Test Agent service when running automated test cases on remote machine

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, automated-tests, microsoft-test-manager

I am currently in the process of setting up an automated test case solution for a project, and I am using Visual Studio 2012, Test Manager 2010, Test Controller 2010 and Test Agent 2010. The TFS Server I am using is 2010, and our automated test case project is in the .NET 4.0 framework.

The setup approach for our automated test case solution is:

-We have a remote machine with the Test Controller and Test Agent installed on them
-Test Manager is configured with a physical environment (in the lab center) that uses the Test Controller and Test Agent on the remote machine
-The Test Settings in Test Manager are also configured to run the tests for a 64 bit machine, which is how the remote machine is configured
-Test cases are then linked with Coded UI tests from our automation solution, executed from Test Manager, which are then run on the remote machine

While I have had success with this setup for automation solutions in Visual Studio 2010, I have encountered a number of issues when trying to work with the 2012 version of the solution.

The latest issue I have run into is that, while I am able to execute the test in Test Manager and have it queue up in the Test Agent on the remote machine, the test never executes.

Looking at the Event Log, I am seeing 3 exception errors that are occurring, 1 for the VSTTAgent and 2 for the VSTTAgentProcess. I have attached each of the errors below in their respective order.

[image: VSTTAgent Error]
[image: VSTTAgentProcess Error 1]
[image: VSTTAgentProcess Error 2]

Has anyone encountered an issue like this before?

Comment: It looks like VS2012 added an interface for that method which doesn't exist in 2010. I'm going to go with this is an impossible scenario. Try upgrading the test controller to 2012.

Comment: Have you installed SP1 on all your 2010 assets?

Comment: I believe that you will need to use VS 2010 to connect and load data from your 2010 Agents.

Comment: Andrew's comment was the correct one - I found out after that each Test Agent and Controller version have to be used with their respective VS version (i.e., 2010 with 2010, and 2012 with 2012).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my comment under the first question, and to Andrew's answer, I discovered that the 2012 agent and controller can't be used with TFS 2010.

As some additional information, I found that our company's build agent (2010) didn't have all of the class library definitions we needed to deploy our 2012 solution properly anyway.

I appreciate everyone's answer to my question, and I hope this helps someone else in the future!